# MOQ 'TestMethod(Action<int> callback)' and be able to 'call' callback

Tags: c#, testing, moq

Oook,
I'm wanting to mock a callback that I know my service will call. For example:

```
public interface ITestMe { void TestMethod(Action<int> callback); }
```

In the application, when calling 'TestMethod' I would pass the callback method to hit after it has run, which will do something based on the parameters. Typically, in this case it's used like this:

```
...
testMe.TestMethod(
    (ret) => 
        {
        if(ret < 0)
            AddToErrorCollection(ret);
        else
            AddToSuccessCollection(ret);
        }
    );
```

What I'd like to do in MOQ is call that anonymous method with a range of values i.e. something like:

```
myMock.Setup(m => m.TestMethod(It.IsAny<Action<int>>())).... //Call that action!!??
```

Is there anyway to do that? 
Is this even the correct way to do it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try this:

```
myMock.Setup(m => m.TestMethod(It.IsAny<Action<int>>())).Callback<Action<int>>((action) => action(4));
```

although this seems a rather convoluted way to essentially test your callback method. Why not test it directly?

Comment: This is true, but in this case the callback method is an anonymous method, so not directly testable (as far as I know)...